# How can I tell Prettier to ignore a package.json file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, prettier

I am using prettier-standard because the project uses the standard for linting.

Following the [prettier pre-commit hook example](https://github.com/prettier/prettier#pre-commit-hook) I am running prettier on commits. However I would like to ignore the package.json file. I tried adding `package.json` to a *.prettierignore* file but this did not work.

Code from the prettier pre-commit hook example that I am using in my package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "precommit": "lint-staged"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
     "*.{js,json,css}": [
       "prettier --write",
       "git add"
     ]
  }
}
```

```

Comment: I just removed json from the matching e.g. `"*.{js,css}"`. Since it uses minimatch, you might be able to include a negative match to exclude `package.json` but still include other json files.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can also use a `.prettierignore` file.

See [the prettier project itself](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/blob/master/.prettierignore) for a reference.

Comment: I missed that part in your question, sorry. Maybe the tool you use in your precommit hook does not take that file into account.

Answer (score 7):

The limitation here is due to how lint-staged is used.
I personally end up using a simple command (fast enough for me), without lint-staged (but still using husky+precommit).

```
prettier --write "**/*.{js,json,css,md}" !package.json
```

This command is in my package.json as a "format" script.

```
"precommit": "yarn format", // can be "npm run format"
"format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,json,css,md}\" \"!package.json\""
```

Please note the escaped quotes.

Comment: You can use single quote instead of the backslash, which is tidy.

`"format": "prettier --write '**/*.{ts,md,json}' '!package.json'"`