# How can we tell Prettier to ignore a specific JSON file?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, prettier, prettier-vscode

I am using VS Code and would like to exclude a specific json file `data.json` from being formatted by Prettier on save. Say it's in the root, then I create a file `.prettierignore` and add a line `data.json` (according to the [docs](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html)).

This works fine with other types of files, but not with json files. In fact, even writing `*.json` will still format the json files.

There is a setting in VS Code

```
JSON > Format:Enable
Enable/disabled default JSON formatter
```

which is enabled. When I disabled it, however, *no json file* will be formatted on save. This is not what I want. I only want to exclude a specific json file. How can I achieve this?

I have already seen the related question [46409892](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46409892/how-can-i-tell-prettier-to-ignore-a-package-json-file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your VS Code formatter is not Prettier by default for JSON (or maybe not your default formatter for all documents ?)

To define a formatter by default, according to [Prettier doc](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode), you have to set your VS Code settings file like this :

```
{
  // For all files
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",

  // For JSON specifically
  "[json]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  }
}
```

Then, you can define ignored files in your `.prettierignore` using same syntax as `.gitignore`.

Comment: Perfect! This solved the issue. Sorry for the late reply. In my settings.json Prettier was already configured as the default formatter, but for json it had:

`"[json]": {"editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.json-language-features"},`

for some reason. I changed it to Prettier and now it works. :)

Comment: Or simply removing that line also works, since Prettier is already the default.